# Porting QT application from Linux to Windows?

Tags: qt, visual-c++, qt4, mingw

Greetings all,

We are developing a QT application (QT 4.6 LGPL version) in Linux platform.All the libraries we use are cross-platform.
Now we want to port it into Windows and continue develop in Windows.
My questions are:

1. Which compiler should we use ,Can we use MinGW or Visual C++ compiler?

2.If its Visual C++ compiler, which Visual Studio version should be used ,can we use 'Visual C++ Studio 2010 express' ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest, by far, is to install QtCreator.  it includes MinGW and simply opens the same project files as on linux.  compile, and go!

A huge advantage of MinGW over VC++ is that it doesn't make you chase circles around getting the right vcredist library for the exact version of the compiler, nor it cares too much about debug/release builds.  To deploy, just be sure to copy the same one or two DLLs you have on the development machine.  A few more for Qt, but these are well-documented on Qt docs.  No hidden surprises.

Comment: +1, I got hit by this redistributable crap (I was naive enough to believe that the actual Microsoft compiler [VS2008] can produce libraries which works on modern windows operating systems [W2K:Ok, WX+Vista: no way]). Solved it by moving to gcc.